# scope: { } with parameters in TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I found one solution for my problem on the internet, but i have a problem that i dont know how to overwrite this:

```
  restrict: 'A',
  scope: {
    file: '=',
    fileName: '='
  },
```

into TypeScript.

I have tried this:

```
            constructor($scope: ng.IScope) {
            var directive: ng.IDirective = {};
            directive.scope = {
                file: '=',
                fileName: '='
            }
        }
```

But it doesnt help, i still have an error:

> The property 'file' does not exist on value of type 'ng.IScope'.

Used this example: http://jsfiddle.net/lsiv568/fsfPe/10/

**Maybe** (or *probably*) I am doing something wrong and I have to fix this error in another way, but I hope that you will lead me to the right solution.

Answer (score 7):

`ng.IScope` doesn't have a 'file'\'filename' property. Simply `extend` the interface. Something like this:

```
interface IMyScope extends ng.IScope
{
  file: any;
  fileName: any;
}

constructor($scope: IMyScope) {
}
```

**Edit**Here's how I create directives with a scope:

```
    class MyDirective implements ng.IDirective {
            public scope: IMyScope;
               // bla bla


            constructor() {
                this.scope = {
                   file: '=',
                   fileName: '='
                };
            }


            this.link = (scope: IMyScope, elem: JQuery, attrs) => {
                 // bla bla
            }
   }
```

Comment: Didnt help. Parameter '$scope' of constructor from exported class has or is using private type 'IMyScope'.

tryed different ways of getting rid of this error - made an export for interface, but the previouse error remained.

Comment: Add more code. The correct thing is to create your interface. I'll edit my code and show you how I create things.

Comment: The code is completely the same that is in example (http://jsfiddle.net/lsiv568/fsfPe/10/) except for basic thing rewritten into typescript (functions, class, link etc...)

Error is here:
`                            return scope.$apply(() => {
                                scope.file = evt.target.result;
                                if (angular.isString(scope.fileName)) {
                                    return scope.fileName = name;
                                }
                            });`

Comment: im using `export class fileDropzone implements ng.IDirective {`

And i try to extend `ng.Iscope`, but later i cant use `IMyScope` for like: `public scope: IMyScope`, the error:
`Parameter '$scope' of constructor from exported class has or is using private type 'myExtdScope'`

Comment: You dont need your scope as a ctor input param. Look at my edit.